# How to create request body for Python Elasticsearch mSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run [a multi search request](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.msearch) on the Elasticsearch Python client. I can run the singular search correctly but can't figure out how to format the request for a msearch. According to the documentation, the body of the request needs to be formatted as:

> The request definitions (metadata-search request definition pairs), as
>   either a newline separated string, or a sequence of dicts to serialize
>   (one per row).

What's the best way to create this request body? I've been searching for examples but can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you follow the demo of [official doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk)(even thought it's for BulkAPI) , you will find how to construct your request in python with the `Elasticsearch` client:

Here is the **newline separated string** way:

```
def msearch():
    es = get_es_instance()

    search_arr = []
    # req_head
    search_arr.append({'index': 'my_test_index', 'type': 'doc_type_1'})
    # req_body
    search_arr.append({"query": {"term" : {"text" : "bag"}}, 'from': 0, 'size': 2})

    # req_head
    search_arr.append({'index': 'my_test_index', 'type': 'doc_type_2'})
    # req_body
    search_arr.append({"query": {"match_all" : {}}, 'from': 0, 'size': 2})

    request = ''
    for each in search_arr:
        request += '%s \n' %json.dumps(each)

    # as you can see, you just need to feed the <body> parameter,
    # and don't need to specify the <index> and <doc_type> as usual 
    resp = es.msearch(body = request)
```

As you can see, the final-request is constructed by several req_unit. 
Each req_unit construct shows below:

```
request_header(search control about index_name, optional mapping-types, search-types etc.)\n
reqeust_body(which involves query detail about this request)\n
```

The **sequence of dicts to serialize** way is almost same with the previous one, except that you don't need to convert it to string:

```
def msearch():
    es = get_es_instance()

    request = []

    req_head = {'index': 'my_test_index', 'type': 'doc_type_1'}
    req_body = {
        'query': {'term': {'text' : 'bag'}}, 
        'from' : 0, 'size': 2  }
    request.extend([req_head, req_body])

    req_head = {'index': 'my_test_index', 'type': 'doc_type_2'}
    req_body = {
        'query': {'range': {'price': {'gte': 100, 'lt': 300}}},
        'from' : 0, 'size': 2  }
    request.extend([req_head, req_body])

    resp = es.msearch(body = request)
```

[Here is](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=308994310da38596e8eb73561bed0c6e) the structure it returns. Read more about [msearch](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html).

Comment: Is this preferred to just using elasticsearch_dsl import MultiSearch?

Comment: @DavidKong This one follow the elasticsearch-py

Comment: Super useful, thanks. Not sure if the API has changed, I found the structure in first example worked without converting the dicts to JSON.

Comment: Me, too. Just use es.msearch(body = search_arr)

Comment: Anyone facing issue with metadata section key error 
remove the 'type': 'doc_type_1' section from req_head

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [elasticsearch-dsl](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you can use the class [MultiSearch](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#multisearch).

Example from the documentation:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import MultiSearch, Search

ms = MultiSearch(index='blogs')

ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='python'))
ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='elasticsearch'))

responses = ms.execute()

for response in responses:
    print("Results for query %r." % response.search.query)
    for hit in response:
        print(hit.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. I am using the same document type and index so I optimized the code to run multiple queries with the same header:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import exceptions as es_exceptions
import json

RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 10
RECONNECT_SLEEP_SECS = 0.5

def msearch(es_conn, queries, index, doc_type, retries=0):
    """
    Es multi-search query
    :param queries: list of dict, es queries
    :param index: str, index to query against
    :param doc_type: str, defined doc type i.e. event
    :param retries: int, current retry attempt
    :return: list, found docs
    """
    search_header = json.dumps({'index': index, 'type': doc_type})
    request = ''
    for q in queries:
        # request head, body pairs
        request += '{}\n{}\n'.format(search_header, json.dumps(q))
    try:
        resp = es_conn.msearch(body=request, index=index)
        found = [r['hits']['hits'] for r in resp['responses']]
    except (es_exceptions.ConnectionTimeout, es_exceptions.ConnectionError,
            es_exceptions.TransportError):  # pragma: no cover
        logging.warning("msearch connection failed, retrying...")  # Retry on timeout
        if retries > RETRY_ATTEMPTS:  # pragma: no cover
            raise
        time.sleep(RECONNECT_SLEEP_SECS)
        found = msearch(queries=queries, index=index, retries=retries + 1)
    except Exception as e:  # pragma: no cover
        logging.critical("msearch error {} on query {}".format(e, queries))
        raise
    return found

es_conn = Elasticsearch()
queries = []
queries.append(
    {"min_score": 2.0, "query": {"bool": {"should": [{"match": {"name.tokenized": {"query": "batman"}}}]}}}
)
queries.append(
    {"min_score": 1.0, "query": {"bool": {"should": [{"match": {"name.tokenized": {"query": "ironman"}}}]}}}
)
queries.append(
    {"track_scores": True, "min_score": 9.0, "query":
        {"bool": {"should": [{"match": {"name": {"query": "not-findable"}}}]}}}
)
q_results = msearch(es_conn, queries, index='pipeliner_current', doc_type='event')
```

This may be what some of you are looking for if you want to do multiple queries on the same index and doc type.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Here's what I did for anybody else...

```
query_list = ""
es = ElasticSearch("myurl")
for obj in my_list:
    query = constructQuery(name)
    query_count += 1
    query_list += json.dumps({})
    query_list += json.dumps(query)
    if query_count <= 19:
        query_list += "\n"
    if query_count == 20:
        es.msearch(index = "m_index", body = query_list)
```

I was beging screwed up by having to add the index twice. Even when using the Python client you still have to include the index part described in the original docs. Works now though!