# Elasticsearch/dataflow - connection timeout after ~60 concurrent connection

Tags: python, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We host elatsicsearch cluster on Elastic Cloud and call it from dataflow (GCP). Job works fine in dev but when we deploy to prod we're seeing lots of connection timeout on the client side.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 570, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "main.py", line 159, in process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 152, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1617, in search
    body=body,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 390, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 365, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 258, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d04e5690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d04e5690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

I increased timeout setting in elasticsearch client to 300s like below but it didn't seem to help.

```
self.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([es_host], http_auth=http_auth, timeout=300)
```

Looking at deployment at https://cloud.elastic.co/deployments//metrics
CPU and memory usage are very low (below 10%) and search response time is also order of 200ms.
What could be the bottleneck here and how we can we avoid such timeouts?

As seen in below log most of requests are failing with connection timeout while successful request receives response very quick:

[image]

I tried ssh into the VM where we experience the connection error. `netstat` showed there were about 60 ESTABLISHED connections to the elastic search IP address. When I curl from the VM to elasticsearch address I was able to reproduce timeout. I can curl fine to other URLs. Also I can curl fine to elasticsearch from my local so issue is only connection between VM and elasticsaerch server.

Does dataflow (compute engine) or ElasticSearch has limitation on number of concurrent connection? I could not find any information online.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of connection you are making? Is it batch or streaming? A piece of code of the connection would help

Comment: This is streaming job and I make connection to elasticsearch via elasticsearch-py library (calling _search REST API). I put simplified python code and shell script here - https://gist.github.com/daisy1754/985411be17773342d73cb408627e461c

Actually after posting this, I made some update so we now use Shared class to share elasticsearch client and also set maxsize to elasticsearch to limit number of connections. It seemed to help but after 8 hours of run or so I again started to see connection timeout

Comment: Are you implementing teardown in your code ?

Comment: I do not. my latest code (above link) get shared elasticsearch in setup so there is nothing to cleanup

Comment: Does your Dataflow job have autoscaling turned on? Did you see worker number increased when the issue occurred? Also, when you sshed into the problematic VM, how busy was the VM running?

Comment: worker get increased but VM is not busy. Both CPU/memory usage is not high and I can see it just stuck at elasticsearch connection

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code! I'll try to share a suggestion to figure out your issue today or tomorrow!

Answer (score 5):

I did a little bit of research about the connector for ElasticSearch. There are a two principles that you may want to try to ensure your connector is as efficient as possible.

**Note** Setting a maximum number of workers, as suggested in the other answer, will probably not help as much (for now) - let's improve utilization from your Beam/Elastic cluster resources, and if we start hitting limits for either, then we can consider restricting # of workers - but right now, you can try to improve your connector.

#### Using bulk requests to external services

The code you provide issues an individual search request for every element coming into the DoFn. As you've noted, this works fine, but it will cause your pipeline to spend too much time waiting on external requests for each element - so your wait for roundtrips will be O(n).

Gladly, the `Elasticsearch` client has an [`msearch` method](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.msearch), which should allow you to perform searches in bulk. You can do something like this:

```
class PredictionFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, ...):
      self.buffer = []
    ...
    def process(self, element):
        self.buffer.append(element)
        if len(self.buffer) > BATCH_SIZE:
          return self.flush()

    def flush(self):
        result = []

        # Perform the search requests for user ids
        user_ids = [uid for cid, did, uid in self.buffer]
        user_ids_request = self._build_uid_reqs(user_ids)

        resp = es.msearch(body=user_ids_request)

        user_id_and_device_id_lists = []
        for r, elm in zip(resp['responses'], self.buffer):
          if len(r["hits"]["hits"]) == 0:
            continue
          # Get new device_id_list
          user_id_and_device_id_lists.append((elm[2],  # User ID
                                              device_id_list))
          

        device_id_lists = [elm[1] for elm in user_id_and_device_id_lists]
        device_ids_request = self._build_device_id_reqs(device_id_lists)

        resp = es.msearch(body=device_ids_request)

        resp = self.elasticsearch.search(index="sessions", body={"query": {"match": {"userId": user_id }}})
        # Handle the result, output anything necessary

    def _build_uid_reqs(self, uids):
      # Relying on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546253/how-to-create-request-body-for-python-elasticsearch-msearch/37187352
      res = []
      for uid in uids:
        res.append(json.dumps({'index': 'sessions'}))  # Request HEAD
        res.append(json.dumps({"query": {"match": {"userId": uid }}}))  # Request BODY

      return '\n'.join(res)
```

#### Reusing the client as it's thread-safe

The `Elasticsearch` client [is also thread safe](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/#thread-safety)!

So rather than creating a new one every time, you can do something like this:

```
class PredictionFn(beam.DoFn):
    CLIENT = None

    def init_elasticsearch(self):
        if PredictionFn.CLIENT is not None:
          return PredictionFn.CLIENT
        es_host = fetch_host()
        http_auth = fetch_auth()
        PredictionFn.CLIENT = Elasticsearch([es_host], http_auth=http_auth, 
            timeout=300, sniff_on_connection_fail=True,
            retry_on_timeout=True, max_retries=2,
            maxsize=5) # 5 connections per client
        return PredictionFn.CLIENT
```

This should ensure that you keep a single client for each worker, and you won't be creating so many connections to ElasticSearch - and thus not getting the rejection messages.

Let me know if these two help, or if we need to try further improvements!

Comment: wow thanks a lot for detailed answer, Pablo! For reusing client, actually my code already utilize beam's shared so all threads are sharing single client.

Comment: I forgot to update this SO question but I also found that there are CLOSE_WAIT sockets that got stuck and probably causing connection timeout as elasticsearch-py is running out of connection pool (I tried increasing maxsize but it didn't help for some reason). I already reported this to elasticsearch-py but can you think of anything from beam/dataflow side that might cause this CLOSE_WAIT sockets?  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1459

Comment: Ah interesting. Could you add a logger in your init_elasticsearch function? I might guess that creating the client every time there could be creating new connections? To be honest, I'm not sure..

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This was red herring. CLOSE_WAIT is not related. I again had the same issue and most of connections are now in ESTABLISHED status :/

While both of answers below are insightful, I don't think they answered the question.

After some more investigation, I find out that somehow elasticsearch-py (or urllib3), in combination with dataflow, will leave connection in `CLOSE_WAIT` status. Once connection got this status, these connections got stuck (OS will not release these sockets because OS thinks application code will close it) so after running job sometime, all of my connections in connection pool are in this CLOSE_WAIT status and therefore I cannot make any new connections. If I don't use connection pool and instantiate elasticsaerch client for each pardo, it just gets worth, somehow connections got stuck even faster.

I reported issue here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1459 but honestly the issue seems deeper in stack, because I had similar issue when I directly used `requests` package's connection pool (which I believe also used urllib3 under the hood).

Comment: thanks for doing the investigation! Do you think this is a Beam issue? Or an issue with one of the other ibraries? Perhaps when deleting the DoFn you also need to close the connections?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow has no limit on the number of outgoing connections.
It uses a K8s cluster under the hood, and every python thread lives into their own docker container.

API calls to Elastic cloud are rate-limited (take a look at the x-rate-limit-{interval,limit,remaining} fields in the response headers).

With Dataflow it is very easy to hit API rate limits if you do a lot of parallel jobs and/or google cloud scales up the nodes of your job to make it faster.

Possible workarounds in your Dataflow / Apache Beam job:

1 -  (no code required) Play with (Dataflow execution parameters)[ https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params] to limit the number of concurrent processing threads.

The three parameters you need to tweak are:

- `max_num_workers` : maximum number of worker instances (machines) running.
- `number_of_worker_harness_threads`: by default 1 thead per CPU your instance has.
- `machine_type`: the instance type you will use.

2 - Implement rate-limit on your code. See Apache Beam [Timely (and stateful) processing processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/)

Comment: When I curl my elasticsearch endpoint (sessions/_search) I don't get any of these rate limit headers. Also shouldn't elasticserver return rate limit error instead of just hanging on the connection?