# How to use msearch() with "q" in ElasticSearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I've been using the standard [Python ElasticSearch client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html) to make single requests in the following format:

```
es.search(index='my_index', q=query, size=5, search_type='dfs_query_then_fetch')
```

I now want to make queries in batch for multiple strings `q`.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546253/how-to-create-request-body-for-python-elasticsearch-msearch) explaining how to use the `msearch()` functionality to do queries in batch. However, msearch requires the full json-formatted request body for each request. I'm not sure which parameters in the query API correspond to just the `q` parameter from `search()`, or `size`, or `search_type`, which seem to be API shortcuts specific to the single-example `search()`.

How can I use `msearch` but specify `q`, `size`, and `search_type`?

Answer (score 0):

I read through the API and figured out how to batch simple search queries:

```py
from typing import List

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

import json

def msearch(
        es: Elasticsearch,
        max_hits: int,
        query_strings: List[str],
        index: str
    ):
    search_arr = []
    
    for q in query_strings:
        search_arr.append({'index': index })
        search_arr.append(
            {
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": q
                    }
            },
            'size': max_hits 
        })
    
    request = ''
    request = ' \n'.join([json.dumps(x) for x in search_arr])
    resp = es.msearch(body = request)
    return resp

msearch(es, query_strings=['query 1', 'query 2'], max_hits=1, index='my_index')
```

EDIT: For my use case, I made one more improvement, which was because I didn't want to return the entire document in the result– for my purpose, I just needed the document ID and its score.

So the final search request object part looked like this, including the `'_source': False` bit:

```py
        search_arr.append(
            {
                # Queries `q` using Lucene syntax.
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": q
                    },
                },
                # Don't return the full profile string, etc. with the result.
                # We just want the ID and the score.
                '_source': False,
                # Only return `max_hits` documents.
                'size': max_hits 
            }
        )
```